# Host name resolution error (DNS) while accessing to app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Recently, I have noticed that many requests to my app service fails due to a DNS issue (on daily basis).

I use the app service to run a web service to my platform (app service is located in west UK).

I get the same errors from both Android&IOS applications being used by my users.

The error says: "unable to resolve host ***.azurewebsites.net"

In addition, I would like to specify that I created a new app service (located in west Europe), but still

get the same errors.

The errors seems to be received randomly, on different times and from different devices.

### Update

I created a new app service and add some simple logic in the client side, in which I switched between the two app services upon dns error detected.

After exploring my logs, I have noticed that sometimes I had success (no dns issue when switching to the secondary app service), and sometimes 
the dns error keep occurring.

Comment: What kind of service plan are you using?  Have you tried to scale up the service plan to check? You could monitor the metric with Azure application insight.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I use the standard 1 small service plan. I will try to scale up the plan to see if it can help. Are DNS error monitored by the app insights?